# while printing how to skip a value which is not in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict

```
x={'a':[1,'inr','in-gaap'],'b':[2,'','in-gaap'],'c':[3,'inr','']}
```

from which I am printing like this:

```
for key,values in x.iteritems():
    print 'value:{0}ref:{1}pre:{2}'.format(x[key][0],x[key][1],x[key][2])
```

It's printing

```
value:1 ref:inr pre:in-gaap
value:2 ref:    pre:in-gaap
value:3 ref:inr pre:
```

But what I want in output is

```
value:1 ref:inr pre:in-gaap
value:2 pre:in-gaap
value:3 ref:inr
```

For values which are not there that values should not be printed.
How can I do this?

Comment: You should be using `values` instead of `x[key]`. That's why your iterating over the items... really, you should just be doing `for values in x.itervalues()`.

Comment: It's not the value that's not in the dict, it's an empty string in a list. This has nothing to do with dictionaries.

Comment: ya i got it now@PeterWood. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NAMES = 'value ref pre'.split()
for key, values in x.iteritems():
    valstrs = ['%s:%s' % (name, value)
               for name, value in zip(NAMES, values)
               if value]
    print ' '.join(valstrs)
```

Comment: I'd take `NAMES = 'value', 'ref', 'pre'` over `NAMES = 'value ref pre'.split()` any day. (And I'd chuck the `valstrs` bit, putting it as a generator expression passed to `' '.join()`.)

Comment: It's a matter of taste, really. I find it a lot quicker to use space rather than `', '` as a token separator. If `NAMES` is module-level, it makes no difference performance-wise. `valstrs` are for readability -- performance for 3-element lists will be roughly the same as for generator expressions.